# postgres: return row even if no row matches in joining table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables, `service_agreement` and `account`. The `account` table contains a foreign key (`service_agreement_id`) to the `service_agreement` table.

Basically what I'm trying to do is determine whether or not a particular account has signed the latest published service agreement for a specific business.

If the account HAS signed the latest published service agreement for a business, nothing would be returned.

If the account HAS NOT signed the latest published service agreement for a business, the agreement would be returned.

I've tried something like the following, but I'm struggling to get the desired result:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT * FROM service_agreement s WHERE business_id = 1 ORDER BY published_at DESC LIMIT 1) AS s
LEFT JOIN account a ON s.id = a.service_agreement_id
WHERE a.user_id = 819;
```

I'm running Postgres 9.5.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query would more appropriately look like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT * FROM 
     ) s LEFT JOIN
     account a
     ON s.id = a.service_agreement_id AND a.user_id = 819;
```

What I think you really want, though, is:

```
select a.*
from account a left join
     (select sa.id
      from service_agreement sa
      where sa.business_id = 1
      order by published_at desc 
      limit 1
     ) sa
     on a.service_agreement_id = sa.id
where sa.id is null;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, thanks a ton for the quick reply. This got me going down the right path. This seems to give me ultimately what I was looking for: `SELECT s.* 
FROM (SELECT * FROM service_agreement s WHERE business_id = 1 ORDER BY published_at desc limit 1) AS s
INNER JOIN account a ON s.id != a.service_agreement_id AND a.user_id = 819;` This results in getting the latest published agreement if the account has not signed it. Not sure if there's a way to optimize this further.